ia there any solution for wrorking the function getchainid in my code
give me the solution to these error to run my code :
App.js:639
Error getting chain ID: a: Client URL " https://polygon-rpc.com/" is invalid.
at new c (http://127.0.0.1:5500/vap/BlockChain-Verification/BlockChain-Based-Document-Verfication-With-IPFS-main/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js:2:530237)
at get_ChainID (http://127.0.0.1:5500/vap/BlockChain-Verification/BlockChain-Based-Document-Verfication-With-IPFS-main/js/App.js:604:27)
at sendHash (http://127.0.0.1:5500/vap/BlockChain-Verification/BlockChain-Based-Document-Verfication-With-IPFS-main/js/App.js:524:3)
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (http://127.0.0.1:5500/vap/BlockChain-Verification/BlockChain-Based-Document-Verfication-With-IPFS-main/upload.html:139:38)
get_ChainID @   App.js:639
the solution of above problem
